# Hibernate. Save only unpersisted objects

Tags: hibernate, insert, unique

I need to make hibernate to save only unpersisted objects. If this object is already persisted, hibernate must do nothing or ruturn the id of persisted object. Of cource equals() and hashCode() methods are owerriden and working fine.
Can I do it somehow via configuration or something like pre insert listener? 
For example:

```
session.beginTransaction();
ElementToPersist element = new ElementToPersist();
element.setName("Element");
element.setValue("Value");

session.save(element);
session.getTransaction().commit();

session.beginTransaction();
ElementToPersist element2 = new ElementToPersist();
element2.setName("Element");
element2.setValue("Value");

session.save(element2);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

In my case the both elements will be persisted with different id's. How can i make hibernate to check the existance of this element before inserting? Can you show the best pratice?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if the elements exist in the database using a query, and insert it only if it doesn't exist. Note that this should be enforced by a database constraing, because you might have a race condition if two transactions check and insert the same element concurrently.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no ability no add the constraints because of abnormal architecture. What can I do if another object has a many-to-one association with this Elements and it must be persisted too?

Comment: Well, you initialize the ManyToOne association with the element that is already in the database, or with the element that you just persisted, depending on the case.

Comment: So, did you mean that i must execute query like  "session.createQuery("from ElementTOPersist as o where o = ?")" and then save the this object manually?

Comment: No. This query would get the element with the same ID as the one you want to persist, which doesn't have one. The query should be "select o from ElementToPersist o where o.name = :name and o.value = :value" (if name and value constitute the functional key of the object). Then, if this query returns something, you must not persist anything. And if it doesn't return anything, then you must persist the object.

Comment: What will be happen when i'll persist the object contains Set<ElementToPersist> mappeb by many-to-one? Will the check-query be ignored? Can I get a little example somewhere? Unfortunately, this object with Set must be unique too.

Comment: Is the pre-insert listerner implementation useful in this situation?

Comment: If you persist several elements at once, and you must check that each of them is unique, then you must indeed check it explicitely. It's pretty rare to persist an entity with many others at once. Especially if the many others are not owned by the one.

Comment: But how to check that the element with Set is unique? Exactly to check that the set is unique.

Comment: Use a loop, and check that each element is unique, or use a query with multiple clauses separated with `or`.

Comment: oh, it will be time-consuming. Now I don't see any profit of hibernate usage. Thank you.

Comment: How would you do it *without* Hibernate? Hibernate is no black magic. It's an ORM. It still has to execute queries.

Comment: Yes, by executing the same queries.